# Connecting a Flux/Publisher/Subscriber to a continual generator

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a class that continually generates and stores new data values (using a thread pool). I want to provide a means for client code ("subscribers") to tap into (connect to) that sequence of new data values. However, if my class has no clients, or all the clients have finished reading from the sequence, I want it to continue generating and storing new values without stopping. When a client connects to that sequence, it receives the newly generated values, but not values generated in the past. Which Project Reactor class (or classes) are suitable for doing this?

I guess I need to represent the sequence of new values using a `Flux`, but which `Flux` class (or factory method) to use?

Answer (score 1):

## Use DirectProcessor

As I understood, what needed is the ability to subscribe to upstream regardless there are subscribers of its or not.

That can be achievable with the support of `DirectProcessor`. Since `Processor` is a combination of `Publisher` and `Subscriber`, it can "run" upstream and continuously listen to incoming signals. At the same time, `DirectProcessor` enables messages demultiplexing, or simply broadcast messages to all available downstream subscribers (if they are listening).

For example, let's consider the following code sample:

```
Flux<Long> intervalFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(500)).log("upstream");
DirectProcessor processor = DirectProcessor.create();

intervalFlux.subscribe(processor);

Thread.sleep(2000);

Disposable downstream1 = processor.log("downstream1")
                                  .subscribe();

Thread.sleep(1000);

downstream1.dispose();

Thread.sleep(1000);

Disposable downstream2 = processor.log("downstream2")
                                  .subscribe();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

As we can see, we subscribed to the upstream using processor, so the interval `Flux` starts generating data. Then we subscribed to the `processor` and waited for 1 second so two events should be observed by downstream1 and 6 logged in general by `log("upstream")` operator. After that, we canceled subscription so the `downstream1` subscriber should stop observing any events but `log("upstream")` should observe intervals still. Then, after another pause, we subscribed to the stream with another `downstrea2` subscriber which should observe another four events.

The general output of the abovementioned code is the following:

```
2019-01-23 15:09:04,246 INFO upstream [main] onSubscribe(FluxInterval.IntervalRunnable)
2019-01-23 15:09:04,249 INFO upstream [main] request(unbounded)
2019-01-23 15:09:04,757 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(0)
2019-01-23 15:09:05,252 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(1)
2019-01-23 15:09:05,751 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(2)
2019-01-23 15:09:06,252 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(3)
2019-01-23 15:09:06,258 INFO downstream1 [main] onSubscribe(DirectProcessor.DirectInner)
2019-01-23 15:09:06,258 INFO downstream1 [main] request(unbounded)
2019-01-23 15:09:06,754 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(4)
2019-01-23 15:09:06,755 INFO downstream1 [parallel-1] onNext(4)
2019-01-23 15:09:07,254 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(5)
2019-01-23 15:09:07,254 INFO downstream1 [parallel-1] onNext(5)
2019-01-23 15:09:07,263 INFO downstream1 [main] cancel()
2019-01-23 15:09:07,755 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(6)
2019-01-23 15:09:08,255 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(7)
2019-01-23 15:09:08,265 INFO downstream2 [main] onSubscribe(DirectProcessor.DirectInner)
2019-01-23 15:09:08,265 INFO downstream2 [main] request(unbounded)
2019-01-23 15:09:08,755 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(8)
2019-01-23 15:09:08,756 INFO downstream2 [parallel-1] onNext(8)
2019-01-23 15:09:09,255 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(9)
2019-01-23 15:09:09,256 INFO downstream2 [parallel-1] onNext(9)
2019-01-23 15:09:09,751 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(10)
2019-01-23 15:09:09,751 INFO downstream2 [parallel-1] onNext(10)
2019-01-23 15:09:10,255 INFO upstream [parallel-1] onNext(11)
2019-01-23 15:09:10,255 INFO downstream2 [parallel-1] onNext(11)
```

As we can see, DirectProcessor enables required behaviors so it can probably fit well there.

## Note

DirectProcessor does not support backpressure so in case backpressure is important, [limitRate operator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#limitRate-int-) operator can be used there.

## See Also

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_direct_processor